# What are the values assigned to a and b?

Tags: c

```
int main()
{
    int a=1,2;
    int b=(3,4,5);
    printf("%d\n",a+b);
}
```

As execution starts from the `main` function then it will read the `a` variable value. I am confused about what value `a` will take. What value will `b` take?

Comment: Since the code won't compile, the answer is that neither `a` nor `b` gets a value.  If you placed parentheses around `1,2` as with the initialization of `b`, then `a` would be assigned `2`, `b` would be assigned `5`, so the value `7` would be printed.  If you eliminated the `,2` characters, `a` would get `1` instead and the value `6` would be printed.  Please don't post uncompilable code — it makes it hard to answer the question coherently because we have to guess how you might fix the code.

Answer (score 2):

1) You can only assign one value to a variable of type 'int'

2) The line `int a=1,2` will throw an error during compilation

3) The variable `b` will be set with the last value in your statement `(3, 4, 5)`

Try running this code and testing for yourself:

```
int main() {
  int a=1;
  int b=(3,4,5);
  printf("Value of a   [%d]\n", a);
  printf("Value of b   [%d]\n", b);
  printf("Value of a+b [%d]\n", a+b);
}
```